# Javascript array return "empty" for first result

Tags: javascript

With javascript, I have a `measurements` variable. It is an array of 4 objects each containing an "id" key.

```
let measurements = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        ...
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        ...
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        ...
    },
    {
        'id': 4,
        ...
    },
]
```

I want to create a new array with ID for the key, but I have a strange result :

**Test 1 :**

```
let list = []

for (let i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++) {
    list[i] = ''
}

console.log(list) // Ok, I have 4 entries ["", "", "", ""]
```

**Test 2 :**

```
let list = []

for (let i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++) {
    list[measurements[i].id] = ''
}

console.log(list) // I have 5 entries  [empty, "", "", "", ""], why ?
```

Comment: Because the ids start at 1.

Comment: The ids go from 1 to 4. Why is it surprising that element 0 is then empty?

Comment: your id is not zero based. indexes are zero based they start from 0 instead of 1

Comment: Thanks, your answers helped me. I have tried and if I have an ID 9 I have 10 entries in my new array. I'm from PHP, it's not familiar to me. How can I have strictly 4 entries in my new table (= 4 measurements = 4 entries)?

Comment: Use an object instead. Or let it be as it is and use `measurements.find()` to pick the correct element when you need it.

Comment: @Gaylord.P You haven't really shown what you want to do with your `list`. You could indeed use an object as suggested by Guy, but it if you want iterate over your list, or want to map all elements to different elements, it might be a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length), the special `.length` own property on array instances will always return an integer one larger than the greatest integer index of the array.

In the following, setting a value for index `2` will therefore ensure that the `.length` property returns `3` for array `arr`, and that the array therefore becomes a sparse array of two empty slots, followed by the value `foo` at index `2`.

```js
const arr = []
arr[2] = 'foo'
console.log(arr.length) // 3
console.log(arr) // [empty, empty, 'foo']
```

In this scenario, the other indexes are literally not present. This is because JavaScript is designed to support [sparse arrays](http://www.martinrinehart.com/frontend-engineering/engineers/javascript/arrays/sparse-arrays.html) (ie. arrays with non-contiguous indices). JavaScript engines sometimes represent missing indexes in arrays as `empty`. Note that some web-based JavaScript editors (like the one used by StackOverflow, render these positions as containing `undefined` (which is incorrect, and possibly a limitation of the transpilation process).

```js
const arr = []
arr[2] = 'foo'
console.log(arr.length) // 3
console.log(arr) // [undefined, undefined, 'foo'] !
```

Remember that in JavaScript arrays are "just objects" for which there is a convention applied for index locations (they are properties with a string name corresponding to a positive integer, eg `'2'`). Once this is understood, it becomes clear how sparse arrays "just work". "Holes" in the array are positions where there is a gap in the continuous zero-based integer sequence represented by these property names.

eg.

```js
Array.from({ '1': 'foo', '3': 'bar', length: 4 }) // [empty, 'foo', empty, 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Array-entries are counted starting at 0. In your loop, you're adding elements for each id.

> let list = []
>
> for (let i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++) {
> list[measurements[i].id] = '' }
>
> console.log(list) // I have 5 entries  [empty, "", "", "", ""], why ?

Each run of the loop adds an item to a specific index in the list-array.

So you start with: []
Then you add an item to the array, at position 1: [empty, ""]. Position one can only exist, if position 0 exists. But you didn't add anything to position 0, so it's empty.

To answer your follow-up questions: if you need the array to find things by id, you would use an object in Javascript:

> {1: "" , 2: "", ...}

If the order of the items is important, you could still use the array and accept that there may be gaps in it.

Answer (score -1):

Array-entries are counted starting at 0. In your loop, you're adding elements for each id. But you start at 1, which means there's going to be one empty.

Either do `id-1` to resolve this:

```
let list = []

for (let i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++) {
    list[measurements[i].id-1] = ''
}

console.log(list)
```

Or change the array itself:

```
let measurements = [
    {
        'id': 0,
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
    },
]
```