# Assigning object to array adds many nulls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to assign an object to an array by key but it ends up with many nulls inside besides the actual object.

First of all, I output data to an HTML `data-*` attribute with PHP:

```
<div id="{{$obj_id}}" data-my-obj="{{json_encode($data)}}"></div>
```

Then I read the data object and the `id` with jQuery, and I assign the the object to an empty array with the `id` as the key (I get the `id` somewhere else above this piece of code):

```
let arr = [];
let myObj = $(`#${id}`).data(`myObj`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj)) // outputs {"data": "some_data"} correctly

if (arr[id] === undefined) {
    arr[id] = []; // in case it was not initialized before
}
arr[id] = myObj;
```

But when I console log the `arr` using `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))` it shows me the following:

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {"data": "some_data"}]
```

I managed to reproduce it here in a snippet but the difference here it only shows 1 `null` instead of 20+:

```js
let id = 1;
let arr = [];
let myObj = $(`#${id}`).data(`myObj`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));

if (arr[id] === undefined) {
    arr[id] = [];
}

arr[id] = myObj;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="1" data-my-obj='{"data":"some_data"}'></div>
```

Comment: create a working snippet with an example

Comment: thanks, I managed to create a similar output in my snippet, just here it shows 1 `null` instead of 20+

Comment: You are never specifying what should be in position 0 (just position 1), which is why there is `null` (no value) in the first element of the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript array return "empty" for first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428191/javascript-array-return-empty-for-first-result)

Comment: It only shows `null` because you are stringifying it. If you `console.log(arr)`, it should show empty slots, not `null`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh I think I see my mistake now, since I'm used to PHP. It's not assigning the data to a key-value pair with key being "1", it's assigning to an array in position `1`. If I want the `id` to be a key and not array position, should I initialize the `arr` as object using `{}` instead?

Comment: You could do that, sure.

Comment: thanks, now that I changed it from `arr = [];` to `arr = {};` it's working. Would you do it differently or that's ok?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let id = 0;
let arr = [];
let myObj = $(`#${id}`).data(`myObj`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));

if (arr[id] === undefined) {
    arr[id] = [];
}

arr[id] = myObj;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="0" data-my-obj='{"data":"some_data"}'></div>
```

remember that the first element of the array starts with 0 not id 1

Comment: thank you, I was used to PHP and that I can assign it as key-value pair where the `id` is the key and not an array position. So I changed `arr = [];` to `arr = {};` and it's working as I intended